# Google cache issues on my reactjs projects

Tags: reactjs, caching, seo

I'm working on the reactjs website. and I upload the reactjs code on the production. now google is crawling all the website as a cache. so we check the cache version like this

cache://websouls.com/

Here the link of the orginal website: https://www.websouls.com/

so google show us the cache website.

so the issue I'm facing is, I got 404 page on each website pages.

I have no idea why I'm having these issues.

[image: This is how it looks like in google cache]

and

[image: This is how it looks like in the google text only version]

I'm using react helemt, to do any SEO stuff in my react pages.

Answer (score 1):

This can have many reasons.
Google Cache is weird.

It might be that the page got indexed, but some bot detection is in place, that makes the site invisible.

The snapshot might not have updated, as the date refers to reindexing and not when the snapshot was taken (I know, weird).

Also since Google Cache doesn't support DOM, this means native Javascript does  not get executed. If for some reason you have a redirect using Javascript, this error might pop up.

I recommend reading through this article: [https://searchengineland.com/why-google-cache-lies-to-you-and-what-to-do-306343#:~:text=Reason%3A%20the%20page%20is%20not,pages%20they%20crawl%20and%20index](https://searchengineland.com/why-google-cache-lies-to-you-and-what-to-do-306343#:%7E:text=Reason%3A%20the%20page%20is%20not,pages%20they%20crawl%20and%20index).

I have had problems with Google Cache before. It's not a big deal, so don't sweat it too much.

Comment: I read this mentioned article, and I cache the website again. I console.log few values words like the what's the current Url of the page etc. so if I hit the "/" route it console log me the value "/search" so I think that's why the google is showing 404 because I have this line in my routes "<Route path="*" element={Page404()} />" so the question is now how we tell the google which page will apears.

Comment: Looks like your caching is working now. You can put your question as solved.

Comment: No, the cache is not working fine, I create a manul route for this but on each page I got the Home page only. That's the main issue.